# Bouncy Castle - Get Hash before sign from TimeStampResponse

Tags: java, c#, asp.net, spring, bouncycastle

I am getting signed hash from TSA by using [`Bouncy Castle`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) like this-

```
TimeStampResponse GetSignedHashFromTsa(byte[] hash)
{
    TimeStampRequestGenerator reqGen = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();

    TimeStampRequest request = reqGen.Generate(
                TspAlgorithms.Sha1,
                hash,
                BigInteger.ValueOf(100)
            );
    byte[] reqData = request.GetEncoded();

    HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.cryptopro.ru/tsp/tsp.srf");
    httpReq.Method = "POST";
    httpReq.ContentType = "application/timestamp-query";
    httpReq.ContentLength = reqData.Length;

    // Write the request content
    Stream reqStream = httpReq.GetRequestStream();
    reqStream.Write(reqData, 0, reqData.Length);
    reqStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse httpResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpReq.GetResponse();

    // Read the response
    Stream respStream = new BufferedStream(httpResp.GetResponseStream());
    TimeStampResponse response = new TimeStampResponse(respStream);
    respStream.Close();

    return response;
}
```

From this function, I can get a [`TimeStampResponse`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/tsp/TimeStampResponse.html) object (same in [***Java***](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) and [***C#***](https://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html)) from a  `byte[]`.

I like to get the `byte[]` from the [`TimeStampResponse`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.4/org/bouncycastle/tsp/TimeStampResponse.html) object in another class. Is there any way?

Thanks in advance for helping.

### Re-

For a better understanding of [Sai Ye Yan Naing Aye](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210779/sai-ye-yan-naing-aye), I am calling the function like this-

```
byte[] hashToSign = ....;
TimeStampResponse response = GetSignedHashFromTsa(hashToSign);
byte[] signedByteToSaveInFile = response.GetEncoded();
```

Then I am saving `signedByteToSaveInFile` in a file. Later I am trying to find the `byte[]` what is signed. Say, I am doing this-

```
byte[] signedByteToSaveInFile = ....; //Read byte array from file
TimeStampResponse previouslyTsaSignedDataResponse = new TimeStampResponse(signedByteToSaveInFile);
```

Now I like to get the byte array what was sent to TSA server before sign from `previouslyTsaSignedDataResponse` object. So, I like to get `byte[] hash` what was sent to TSA server to sign. In another word, I like to get the main content before sign.

Think, now the question is more clear.

Comment: You want encoded byte[] request data in your response? Not too clear your question :)

Comment: Hi, please check updated question. I have added a `re` section for a better understanding so that you can easily understand. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is not much clearer to me. If you need the "byte[] hashToSign" for later usage simply save it a byte array to a file a reload it later. You cannot get the value from the the "TimeStampResponse previouslyTsaSignedDataResponse".

Comment: That is not possible, because I am trying to retrieve the `byte [] hashToSign` from signed byte array because I like to verify that from stored signed byte array.

Comment: _I like to get byte[] hash what was sent to TSA server to sign_: The TSA concatenates the received Hash1 with a timestamp, generates another Hash2 from this and signs it (signature). Signature and timestamp are sent back to the recipient. Hashing is not reversible, i.e. from Hash2 the original data Hash1 + timestamp, can no longer be reconstructed.

Comment: In that case, can I verify that the timestamp signature byte array is created from the provided byte array that was sent to server?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping#Checking_the_timestamp), which describes the verification process. In the section above, the creation of a trusted timestamp is described.

Comment: Can you call response.getTimeStampToken() and check TimeStampToken  for your original TimeStampResponse and new TimeStampResponse (previouslyTsaSignedDataResponse) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it myself like this-

```
bool ValidateTimestamp(TimeStampResponse tr, byte[] hash)
{
    try
    {
        TimeStampRequestGenerator reqGen = new TimeStampRequestGenerator();
        TimeStampRequest request = reqGen.Generate(
                TspAlgorithms.Sha1,
                hash,
                BigInteger.ValueOf(100)
            );
    
        tr.Validate(request);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
    return tr.GetFailInfo() == null;
}
```